# SSL site error ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT - MAC OSX - Chrome Only

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I am trying to access a site that requires an SSL key. I am using Chrome (latest) on Mac OSX 10.14.4.

Browsing the site I get the following error:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection site.com didn’t accept
>   your login certificate, or one may not have been provided. Try
>   contacting the system admin.
>
> ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT

I can access the site on Safari, Firefox, and Chrome for Windows (using a VM). It is only Chrome for Mac that gives me an error.

When I access the SSL keys in the Chrome Preferences, I am taken to the OSX Keychain app.

The key exists in the keychain, and the permissions are set to allow use from any app (I have also tried setting this to manual and specifically setting allow with Chrome).

When I browse to the site in chrome, I am asked to pick the SSL key to use - the key is detected and I select it from the list (it is the only one available anyway).

I am completely out of ideas. Any thoughts on what I can do to fix this?